# does usb 3.0 port support usb 2.0 devices for laptop

Tags: usb

i am going to buy a Seagate 2 TB Back Up Plus Portable 2.5 inch Drive USB 3.0 2 TB External Hard Disk. But I have a DELL Inspiron 15r laptop, which is USB 2.0. Do USB 3.0 ports support USB 2.0 devices?

Comment: Flagged, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are backwards compatible see [Here >>](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/998240-should-usb-20-devices-work-with-usb-30-ports/)

Slightly unrelated to programming however...